# Swift version of this code for calling popover programatically being called from uitableviewcell

Tags: swift

Just wondering if anyone can translate this in a way this to swift for me I don't read non swift code proficiently enough yet to translate this fully. I am basically looking to have a UIViewcontroller I created with the popover size present when the user selects the cell from a tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad"
                                             bundle:nil];
UITableViewController *detailController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableSettingDetails"];

self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailController];

self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 416);
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView
                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                      animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var popoverController = UIPopoverController()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard_iPad", bundle: nil)

    let detailController : UITableViewController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableSettingDetails") as! UITableViewController

    self.popoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: detailController)

    self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 416)

    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    self.popoverController.presentPopoverFromRect(cell.bounds, inView: cell.contentView, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
}
```